# How to get ng-template innerHTML to component

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-template

I want to get the innerHTML of ng-template to my component. Something like

HTML

```
<my-comp [template]="myTemplate"></my-comp>
<ng-template #myTemplate></ng-template>
```

TS

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() template: string | TemplateRef<any>;

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.template);
  }

}
```

Comment: just to clarify: you want the html provided by a parent component to be used as the child component's template?

Comment: yes.. we can get the template if inside the component(using viewChild). but How to do that when the template isn't part of the component @BeetleJuice

Comment: So the component itself is just an empty shell until template is provided from the outside

Comment: you want to send the HTML content as input from another component and bind to the template? correct?

Comment: No exactly can be an empty shell. But maybe. If this problem is solved. It can be used in many ways like even an empty shell. Can have custom templates and so on @BeetleJuice

Comment: you can get the innerHTML only if it is of type ElementRef or ViewChild. Also `@Input` can't be a `TemplateRef` so if your requirement is elaborated i will suggest you ways to implement

Comment: yes @Aravind...

Comment: @SibiRaj I m sorry i didnt get you

Comment: That was for your previous comment @Aravind

Comment: @Aravind. I have seen something similar to my requirement but I cannot figure that out exactly . check here https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/7f9ffc7382e3e76f4e326dd0e79d6b3782eb87e9/src/popover/popover.ts#L97

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158722/discussion-between-aravind-and-sibi-raj).

Answer (score 3):

Since you only require a shell into which a template will be injected, consider using a Directive instead of a component.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[template-host]'
})
export class HostDirective{

  @Input('template-host') set templateHtml(value){
    this.hostElement.innerHTML = value;
  }

  private hostElement:HTMLElement;

  constructor(elementRef:ElementRef){
    this.hostElement = elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
}
```

Now you can apply that directive to any element, and the provided `template-host` binding will cause html injection in that element. For example:

```
<!-- The div will contain the html in myTemplate -->
<div [template-host]="myTemplate"></div>
```

[**Live demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k7ddsn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

If your class actually has a template, but you want to inject html into only a portion of that template, [learn about transclusion](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content)

Comment: thanks. but that gives the template of the host element, but i want from ng-template

Comment: I see. Why not store the template as a string property of the parent component? Why do you require it to be inside the ng-template in the parent view?

Comment: So You mean Just a plain string?

Comment: @SibiRaj Yes: whatever html string you would have written in the template, stored as a plain string in a class property.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: This approach doesn't appear to work in Angular 8.  I get the following line of text added to the innerHTML. 
` (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`
Try using a standard directive instead.

Comment: Is it possible to pass `ngTemplateOutletContext`?

Answer (score 3):

I needed to solve exactly the same problem today and found this question. I ended up looking into ng-bootstrap in order to see how they did it, and ultimately it's a fairly simple solution.

You need to get hold of ViewContainerRef that you want your string/TemplateRef to be inserted to. This can be either the host element (ViewContainerRef injected in constructor) or ViewChild. e.g:

```
constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
```

or

```
@ViewChild('someDiv', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;
```

next, in ngOnInit() you need to do an if/else depending if the input is TemplateRef or string and assign it to viewContainerRef:

```
if (this.template instanceof TemplateRef) {
   this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(<TemplateRef<any>>this.template);
} else {
    this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.template;
}
```

Hope that helps!